# Can chrome know if there is a window maximized or not in front during selenium automation?

Tags: selenium, perl, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing a really annoying issue trying to atuomate one project site tests.

The tests goes through multiple pages filling some forms.

**I have the following scenarios**:

1. I start the script, the chromedriver is opened and maximized. I keep my focus on the page while script runs. I go without problem through the whole test.
2. I start the script, the chromedriver is opened and maximized. Now I put a window in front, but this window is not maximized, so I can see in background how the script is filling the forms but my widow focused is another one. I go without problem throught the whole test.
3. I start the script, the chromedriver is opened and maximized. Now I put another window in front but this time the window is maximized and I can not see the script in background. Now I can go through some of the forms, but it gets stucked in one of them not being able to open some select boxes or writing text.

**Things that I have checked/observed**:

1. I'm not able to think a logical reason of this happening. If I run the same 3 steps in firefox with geckdriver they always work.
2. I have observed that when I switch from my window maximized on top, to chrome, I seem to find a gray page for some ms as it would be not rendered yet, I was able to make this screenshot by recording the screen:
   [image: gray image]

**Environment**:

1. I'm using perl with `Selenium::Chrome` together with `ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20`
2. The site being tested is built on `JSF` and developers have not included any specfic focus requirement.
3. This ocurs always using the process described in step 3.

**Hypothesis**:
Somehow chrome knows if is visible in screen and then its behaivour of elements loaded in DOM changes? I can still see find elements with selenium, but its behaivour on click does not work as expected.

Furthermore, in one of the steps where I was facing this issue, there was a button which would work with:

```
$driver->execute_script("arguments[0].click()", $element);
```

But not with

```
$element->click()
```